# Django QuerySet.update() fails on MySQL if a subquery references the base table

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, django-oscar, django-mysql

I am trying to make this transaction mysql compatible. As mysql don't allow the current operation. MySQL doesn't allow updating the table you are already using in an inner select as the update criteria.

Getting this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1093, "You can't specify target table 'catalogue_category' for update in FROM clause")
```

Code:

```
included_in_non_public_subtree = self.__class__.objects.filter(
    is_public=False, path__rstartswith=OuterRef("path"), depth__lt=OuterRef("depth")
)
self.get_descendants_and_self().update(
    ancestors_are_public=Exists(
    included_in_non_public_subtree.values("id"), negated=True)
)
```

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/pull/3050#pullrequestreview-461576714

Answer (score 0):

You can do subquery by yourself. Split one query into multiple queries.

e.g.

```py
included_in_non_public_subtree = not self.__class__.objects.filter(
    is_public=False, path__rstartswith=OuterRef("path"), depth__lt=OuterRef("depth")
).exists()

self.get_descendants_and_self().update(
    ancestors_are_public=included_in_non_public_subtree,
)
```

Comment: can you provide any hint?

Comment: not working. giving this error ```ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.```

Comment: @SobanJaved could your paste the traceback or more detail about `self.__class__`?